# Can Idris try multiple hints for auto proofs?

Tags: idris

In this example

```
%hint
lemma1: S a `LTE` S b -> a `LTE` b
lemma1 = ?todo1

myMinus: (a, b: Nat) -> {auto prf: b `LTE` a} -> Nat
myMinus (S a') (S b') = a' `myMinus` b' -- automatically uses lemma1
myMinus a b = ?todo2
```

Idris is able to automatically use `lemma1` where it's needed. Now I add a second lemma

```
%hint
lemma2: S a `LTE` b -> a `LTE` b
lemma2 = ?todo3
```

between `lemma1` and `myMinus`. Now Idris doesn't find `lemma1` anymore, probably because it only tries `lemma2`, and I have to specify it manually.

Is there a way, that I can have both `lemma1` and `lemma2` with `%hint` in context and let Idris automatically choose the correct one?

Comment: I think this should be filed as an issue on GitHub. My wild guess is that Idris adds hints on stack (list) as it processes the code and then searches for the first entry and never tries another hint with the same conclusion.